# mutate() with an if/else function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an example dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(cust = sample(1:100, 1000, TRUE),
             channel = sample(c("WEB", "POS"), 1000, TRUE))
```

that I'm trying to mutate

```
get_channels <- function(data) {
    d <- data
    if(unique(d) %>% length() == 2){
        d <- "Both"
    } else {
        if(unique(d) %>% length() < 2 && unique(d) == "WEB") {
            d <- "Web"
        } else {
            d <- "POS"
            }
        }
    return(d)
}
```

This works without issue and on small dataframes, it takes no time at all.

```
start.time <- Sys.time()

df %>%
    group_by(cust) %>%
    mutate(chan = get_channels(channel)) %>%
    group_by(cust) %>% 
    slice(1) %>%
    group_by(chan) %>%
    summarize(count = n()) %>%
    mutate(perc = count/sum(count))

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

> Time difference of 0.34602 secs

However, when the data frame gets rather large, say, on the order of >1000000 or more `cust`, my basic `if/else` fx takes much, **much** longer.

How can I streamline this function to make it run more quickly?

Answer (score 5):

You should use a data.table for this.

```
setDT(df)
t1 = Sys.time()
df = df[ , .(channels = ifelse(uniqueN(channel) == 2, "both", as.character(channel[1]))), by = .(cust)]

> Sys.time() - t1
Time difference of 0.00500083 secs

> head(df)
   cust channels
1:   37     both
2:   45     both
3:   74     both
4:   20     both
5:    1     both
6:   68     both
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Any idea if this can be sped up in the `dplyr` framework?

Comment: @Steven Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience with dplyr. data.table is generally faster though.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in base R using something like that:

```
web_cust <- unique(df$cust[df$channel=="WEB"])
pos_cust <- unique(df$cust[df$channel=="POS"])

both <- length(intersect(web_cust, pos_cust))
web_only <- length(setdiff(web_cust, pos_cust))
pos_only <- length(setdiff(pos_cust, web_cust))
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(cust = sample(2e6, 1e7, TRUE),
                 channel = sample(c("WEB", "POS"), 1e7, TRUE), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster `dplyr` version that takes about 1/3 the time but is probably still slower than the data table version. `uniqueN` borrowed from @Kristoferson answer.

```
 df %>%
    group_by(cust) %>%
    summarize(chan = if_else(uniqueN(channel) == 2, "Both", as.character(channel[1]))) %>%
    group_by(chan) %>%
    summarize(n = n() ) %>%
    mutate(perc = n /sum(n))
```

Also, your orginal can be improved significantly by optimizing your function like this:

```
  get_channels <- function(data) {
    ud <- unique(data)
    udl <- length(ud)
    if(udl == 2) {
      r <- "Both"
    } else {
      if(udl < 2 && ud == "WEB") {
        r <- "Web"
      } else {
        r <- "POS"
      }
    }
    return(r)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

And some timings...

I tried three different alternatives in both `dplyr` and `data.table`: (1) `ifelse` (see @Kristofersen's answer), (2) `if` / `else` (because the `test` is of length 1), and (3) vector indexing. Unsurprisingly, the main difference is between `dplyr` and `data.table` and not among alternative 1-3.

For 1000 customers, `data.table` is about 7 times faster. For 10000 customers it's about 30 times faster. For 1e6 customers, I only tested `data.table`, not a very large difference between alternatives.

```
# 1000 customers, 2*1000 registrations 
df <- data.frame(cust = sample(1e3, 2e3, replace = TRUE),
                 channel = sample(c("WEB", "POS"), 2e3, TRUE))

library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table) 

microbenchmark(dp1 = df %>%
                 group_by(cust) %>%
                 summarise(res = ifelse(n_distinct(channel) == 1, channel[1], "both")),
               dp2 = df %>%
                 group_by(cust) %>%
                 summarise(res = if(n_distinct(channel) == 1) channel[1] else "both"),
               dp3 = df %>%
                 group_by(cust) %>%
                 summarise(res = c("both", channel[1])[(n_distinct(channel) == 1) + 1]),
               dt1 = setDT(df)[ , .(channels = ifelse(uniqueN(channel) == 2, "both", channel[1])), by = cust],
               dt2 = setDT(df)[ , .(channels = if(uniqueN(channel) == 2) "both" else channel[1]), by = cust],
               dt3 = setDT(df)[ , .(res = c("both", channel[1])[(uniqueN(channel) == 1) + 1]), by = cust],
               times = 5, unit = "relative")

# 1e3 customers
# Unit: relative
#  expr       min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
#   dp1 7.8985477 8.176139 7.9355234 7.676534 8.0359975 7.9166933     5
#   dp2 7.8882707 8.018000 7.8965098 8.731935 7.8414478 7.3560530     5
#   dp3 8.0851402 8.934831 7.7540060 7.653026 6.8305012 7.6887950     5
#   dt1 1.1713088 1.180870 1.0350482 1.209861 1.0523597 0.7650059     5
#   dt2 0.8272681 1.223387 0.9311628 1.047773 0.9028017 0.7795579     5
#   dt3 1.0000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.0000000     5

# 1e4 customers
# Unit: relative
#  expr        min         lq       mean    median        uq        max neval
#   dp1 40.8725204 39.5297108 29.5755838 38.996075 38.246103 17.2784642     5
#   dp2 40.7396141 39.4299918 27.4476811 38.819577 37.886320 12.7265756     5
#   dp3 41.0940358 39.7819673 27.5532964 39.260488 38.317899 12.4685386     5
#   dt1  1.0905470  1.0661613  0.7422082  1.053786  1.034642  0.3428945     5
#   dt2  0.9052739  0.9008761  1.2813458  2.111642  2.356008  0.9005391     5
#   dt3  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.0000000     5

# 1e6 customers, data.table only
# Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   dt1 1.146757 1.147152 1.155497 1.164471 1.156244 1.161660     5
#   dt2 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000     5
#   dt3 1.084442 1.079734 1.253568 1.106833 1.098766 1.799935     5
```